# How to install a NTP Client into a yocto-base Linux distribution?

Tags: ntp, yocto

I'm developing a yocto-base Linux distribution by **zeus** yocto release.
I need to add a NTP client to the distribution but I don't need to install the NTP server inside the image.

I have found the recipe:
`meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support /ntp/ntp_4.2.8p15.bb`
that is relative to Network Time Protocol (NTP).

The recipe contains following info about it:

> SUMMARY = "Network Time Protocol daemon and utilities"
> DESCRIPTION = "The Network Time Protocol (NTP) is used to
> synchronize the time of a computer client or server to
> another server or reference time source, such as a radio
> or satellite receiver or modem."

The previous info doesn't explain if the recipe installs a NTP Server or a NTP Client or both.

What I need is a NTP client application that is able to connect to a configurable NTP server and get the current date and time.

The following instruction:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "ntp"
```

is not suitable because adds to the yocto image the NTP Server which is called `ntpd`.

What's the package that I have to add to the image to include a client NTP? Is included in the previous recipe or I have to find a different recipe?

Thanks

Comment: `ntpd` can act as a NTP server, but also as an advanced NTP client that "learns" the characteristics of the local system clock and compensates for its systematic error. `ntpdate` is the simple "fetch the time once and done"-type client.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks. I have read your comment with attention only now. I have installed `ntpdate` in my distribution, by for now I have not use in production the NTP protocol. When I'll restart with it I'll remember your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and test the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441233/ntp-recipe-didnt-install-ntpdate-files).
The answer of that question is helpful for me too.

If I add:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "ntpdate"
```

to my image I install only `ntpdate` and the service `ntpdate.service` without installing `ntpd` and its service.

This is what I need to do.

---

Useful the link to the [ntpdate manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpdate) to know information about ntpdate.